# Problema con find en cake php

Tags: mysql, cakephp

Tengo que hacer unas consultas a una base de datos y solo para probar si me consulta lo que estoy haciendo son unas pruebas pero no me funciona

**Modelo Cliente**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

/**
 * CakePHP Cliente
 * @author ingenieriaseadog
 */
class Cliente extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'empresa' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'cliente' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'direccion' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'telefono' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'informacion' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        ),
        'horario' => array(
            'rule' => 'notBlank'
        )
    );
}
```

**Controller**, aquí esta el problema, aquí uso el find e intento devolver lo que me trae de la BD

```
public function fullClient() {

//        $information = $this->data['Cliente']['informacio'];
        $client = $this->data['Cliente']['cliente'];
        //$posicion_coincidencia = strrpos($cadena_de_texto, $cadena_buscada, -20);
//        $this->Flash->error(__($hola));
        $this->loadModel('Cliente');
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Cliente->create();
            if ($this->Cliente->save($this->request->data)) {
                $hola = $this->Cliente->find('all', array(
                    'fields' => array('id')));
                $this->Flash->success(__($hola));
                return $this->request->data;
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
        }
    }
```

**Error que saca**
[image: Error]

**Estructura de la BD**
[image: BD]

Comment: `__($hola)` le estás pasando el resultado de tu consulta, cuando debería de ser un texto.

Comment: Y como extraigo el texto de la consulta, ósea lo que quiero decir es como hago para que lo que hay en:
´$hola´
 Lo pueda extraer para devolver el dato que me interesa ?

Comment: al usar `find('all', [...])` siempre te regresa un arreglo, y estás obteniendo solo los id's(¿porqué traduces ids?), no se que versión de cake utilices, pero puedes ver en esta liga la información. https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#

Comment: Entonces según te entiendo debería ser  
´$hola['id'][0]´

O me equivoco ?

Comment: Ya lo solucione

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución

```
$consult = $this->Cliente->find('all', array(
                    'conditions' => array('cliente LIKE ' => $client)));
                $id_client = $consult[0];
```

En `$consult` guardo la consulta, la cual es equivalente a `SELECT id FROM clientes AS Cliente WHERE cliente LIKE $client` 
Donde `$client` es un nombre de cliente ingresado en un formulario por el cual quiero buscar el id, en mi caso hay algunos clientes que tienen el mismo nombre ya que apenas estoy en la versión de prueba, por lo cual mas adelante se hara una validación para que solo exista un usuario con el mismo nombre, pero por el momento  se obtiene la linea del primer usuario con ese nombre lo cual se almacena en `$id_client` y de ahí yo devuelvo el id `$this->Flash->success(__($client.var_dump($id_client['Client']['id'])));`, pero mas adelante seria para hacer un insert en otra tabla.

Comment: Una sugerencia, si quieres evitar usar `$consult[0]`, puedes usar `->find('first', $options)`, con _first_ traerá un solo registro, es útil cuando estás seguro que tendrás una sola coincidencia

Comment: Hola @Andrés. Gracias por agregar la respuesta a tu pregunta... Además de indicar una posible solución, sería bueno agregar al menos una pequeña descripción. Pensemos en que si la idea es que sea útil a otros usuarios, los que recién están empezando con esto encontrarían mucho más útil algo de recto que intente describirlo.

Comment: Entonces seria cambiar el all por first?

Con el código que envie que cambiaria ademas del first?